# HTML and CSS animate failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    var menu = $('.ban-top');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 190) {
        menu.addClass('fixmenu');
    } else {
        menu.removeClass('fixmenu');
    }
});
```

```css
.ban-top{
  background:#000;
    padding: 0px 0;
}
.fixmenu{
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I want to achieve expand or bottom down animation when scrolled.
I have tried a few methods but all of them failed.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: Please provide html. You forgot to put  html.

Comment: my actual code is huge.. The menu gets fixed when i scroll down. But i want to animate when i add class. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does $(window) scroll top return the correct answer.  If not try:
Math.max ($(html).scrollTop (), $('body').scrollTop ());
If scroll overflow is occurring in some other html element refer to it.

Comment: my actual code is huge.. The menu gets fixed when i scroll down. But i want to animate when i add class. thanks

Comment: Does the .ban-top element has any transforms or perspective related css properties?